# I cannot observe some android states from NetworkInfo.DetailedState either on device or on emulator

Tags: android, networking

There are couple of possible states in [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html) class of Android. Currently I log the detailed state information of the device/emulator each 100ms but have never seen the states other than CONNECTED, CONNECTING, DISCONNECTED. I tried from Emulator Control tab of Eclipse switching Voice and Data status to roaming, denied, searching etc. but again couldn't observe the other states in the logs.

Is there a way to put the device or the emulator to other states such as AUTHENTICATING, SCANNING, SUSPENDED etc.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Even if I tried to log it while driving where there could be different states, I couldn't observe it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a real device to test. The emulator may have simplified functionalities.